# In map method :Trying to set a key to each component instance

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to give my  a key in the Counters component however i am getting the following error message:

Counter: `key` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned.

However when i remove the key i get a warning that a key is needed

my code is as follows:

counter.jsx:

```
       import React, {Component} from 'react';

    class Counter extends Component{
        state={
            count: 0,

        };


        h

andleIncrement=()=>{
        this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1})
    };





    render(){

        console.log(this.props);


        return (
        <div>
            <span className={this.badgeClasses()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
            <button onClick={this.handleIncrement} className='btn btn-secondary btn-sm'>Increment</button>
        </div>
        );
    }

    formatCount()
    {   
        let count=this.state.count;
        return count===0 ? 'zero': count;

    }

    badgeClasses()
    {
        let classes= "badge m-2 badge-";
        classes+= this.state.count === 0 ? "warning" :"primary";
        return classes;
    }
    }

    export default Counter;
 In my counters.jsx :

import React, {Component} from "react";
import Counter from "./counter";

class Counters extends Component
{ state=
    {
        counters:[
            { id:10, value:1},
            { id:2, value:2},
            { id:30, value:3},
            { id:49, value:0},
        ]
    };

render(){    
return(
<div>
    {this.state.counters.map(
        counter=> <Counter key={counter.id} value={counter.value}/>)
    }

</div>

);
}
}

export default Counters;
```

Dont understand why this will not work.
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Inside child components we cannot access key prop as it is inbuilt prop to identify the unique child components. As a work around you can give another prop name instead of key to access that variable. You can know more about key prop here https://kentcdodds.com/blog/understanding-reacts-key-prop

Answer (score 0):

When rendering a list of elements a unique `key` prop should be passed to each corresponding child which will help React identify which child element has changed or got added, or got removed across re-renders which will help give the elements a stable identity. The `key` prop is there to help react, you should not try to access it inside your component.

In your use-case, it seems you need to access the `counter.id` in the `Counter` component. The solution would be to pass a prop with name `id` to the `Counter` component, for example

```js
class Counters extends Component { 
  state = {
        counters:[
            { id:10, value:1},
            { id:2, value:2},
            { id:30, value:3},
            { id:49, value:0},
        ]
    };

render() {    
   return (
     <div>
      {
        this.state.counters.map(
          counter=> <Counter key={counter.id} id={counter.id} value={counter.value}/>)
      }
     </div>
  );
 }
}
```

You can access the `id` for the counter as `this.props.id` in your `Counter` component.

Comment: I am trying to give a key to each counter using the map method

Comment: Yes indeed. The error `key is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in undefined being returned` is occurring because somewhere in your code you are trying to access the `key` as `this.props.key`.

Comment: if i remove key from here:this.state.counters.map(
          counter=> <Counter key={counter.id} id={counter.id} value={counter.value}/>) then it states that a key is needed; unsure how to rectify this

Comment: You should be passing a key but not trying to access it.